# How to get all shipping costs for all countries for a product in Magento backend?

Tags: php, magento

I'm currently working on a Magento backend plugin to create widgets for products. I'm trying to get a list of Shipping costs for a product for every country.

What I've got:

I've got a backend controller that loads a product model and I get all the data I need from this model.

The problem is getting a list of shipping costs for each country that is defined. How can I do that?

I've tried to use the example (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/EcomDev/extension/3860/ecomdev_productpageshipping) posted by ʍǝɥʇɐɯ in the comments. But this is not working, I always get an empty array.

```
$addToCartInfo = array("estimate"=> array("country_id"=> "US"), "product"=> "1", "related_product" => "", "qty" => "1" ); 
$product->setAddToCartInfo($addToCartInfo);

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress->setCountryId('US');
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true);


$request = new Varien_Object($addToCartInfo);
$request->setQty(1);

$quote->addProduct($product, $request);
$quote->collectTotals();

$rateResult = $shippingAddress->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
```

Is there any difference between frontend and backend in this example that makes this code unusuable? How can I do that in the backend?

Comment: Have you tried `Mage::getModel('shipping/shipping')->collectRatesByAddress()`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a module somewhere on Magento extensions that does that - maybe have a look for it first and re-use their code.

Comment: Can you remember the name of the module? Otherwise that could last long.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/EcomDev/extension/3860/ecomdev_productpageshipping note the mention of '- Added "Include cart items" option'

Comment: I've tried to copy the code of the extension you posted, but that does not work. Could you have a look at my edited question?

Comment: I think I overlooked the word 'backend' earlier - my apologies for leading you astray. However, this I can share with you. Open the code of any shipping module and it loops through the items in the current quote. Therefore it is not a case of every item having a shipping rate per se. Therefore you might want to approach the problem differently, even if that means calculating your shipping in Excel spreadsheet and importing a new attribute that you then add to the products grid.

Comment: Isn't there a possibility to easily simulate frontend in the backend?
I will try your tip with the shipment modules but the Excel method is not possible for me.

Thanks so far!